# FileLoadException Unhandled on dll load

Tags: c#

How to solve this exception

> Could not load file or assembly 'OpenCvSharp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6adad1e807fea099' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 0):

It Could be a version issue, make sure the OpenCvSharp is Version=1.0.0.0

And also check GAC version

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It just means that application during execution can't find an `application \ third party dll` and hence is complaining that.

The assembly’s name, culture, public key or version may be the cause of this issue.

So please try to add this reference again and rebuild the application.

Trouble may be with OpenCvSharp.dll files on your system with a version number of dll
Check version in the GAC, in the app folders.

just recompiled OpenCvSharp.dll  and this error would clear.

[**MSDN has the answer for same issue but for different dll**](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/55770fdb-9946-459e-98d3-eca93102671c/the-located-assemblys-manifest-definition-does-not-match-the-assembly-reference?forum=clr)